# Data structure for optimal condition-based labeling

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-theory

lately I've been facing an issue on deciding on suitable approach for this problem. An app is given a config file, which contains records describing a category of item. Every category consists of two values: "Label" and "Value". "Label"s are not necessarily unique but their combination with the "Value" is uniqe, e.g.

```
Label Value
A     1
A     2
```

is valid, whereas

```
Label Value
A     1
A     1
```

is not a valid configuration. Along with "Label" and "Value" there are also other properties of the config, corresponding to the properties of the data records incoming to the app from the second source (more on that in a second). The value in such a column/property is either null or a "check" written in our company-internal language-like code. This check needs to pass so that an "Item" (the data record from the second source) can be labeled accordingly. So, for example

```
Label Value FileName
A     1     <some_regex>
A     2
```

If an app is given this config and the incoming Item would look like this:

```
Item:
   some_property: 5,
   FileName: "some string passing the regex"
```

it would be labeled as **A1** but if the FileName property were to fail on the FileName test, then it would be labeled as **A2**. Now, there are a lot of properties that are being tested and the number of different tests inside every property is also quite big and both of these will only rise with time. Right now there's a script that just goes through the whole config, fires every test and the result is a category which, obviously, passed all the tests that were needed. My task is to find a way of optimising the process (right now it takes over an hour to label all the records that are incoming every day).

@EDIT:
In the scenario above there are only two label-value pairs with only one property and one test. We expect the config to be much more complicated, consisting of many properties with different tests for each one. We also allow the situation in which the item won't be identified as it won't pass any combination of tests. More real-life-like example would look something like that:

```
Label Value FileName    Property2          Property3   Property4
A     1     <some_regex>
A     2                 <some_boolean_test>            <some_different_boolean test>
B     5                                                <some_other_test>
```

etc.

I initially thought that a good data structure will be enough to make it faster when labelling and started thinking about using tree (or graph) approach - building a tree where every tree "layer" would be a property and nodes living in this layer would contain "checks" for this property, the last layer would be the Label-Value pair. Doing DFS for every item would, I guess, make it significantly faster - however I've stumbled upon issues with that approach.

My biggest concern is that, when building a tree, I have no confidence that the last layer that I'll choose will be discriminative enough to always point to one Label-Value pair. If, for example, there was a node with two leaves, then doing that node's test wouldn't tell me which pair to choose. And dynamically choosing this last layer would be, I guess, really hard if not impossible when building a tree.

Is there any data structure that would address this task, and specifically the given issue, in a more confident way? How would you approach this problem? Is there any algorithm that would help me out in any of the steps in this issue? Thank you in advance, if you have any more questions about the problem then I'll be more than happy to edit it and fill any gaps I might've made.

Comment: Q: So _every_ item that does not pass the test gets labelled A2?

Comment: Q: Another way of asking the same questions: Does every item end up with every label, usually with the test failing values, but the values of a few labels for each item are set to the test passing value?

Comment: @ravenspoint thanks for asking those questions. In this particular scenario yes, every item that wouldn't pass the test for A1 would get labeled as A2, but I guess that this isn't the most generic situation as we expect items to be unidentified as well, meaning that they didn't manage to get labelled as any of the existing label. It is possible for label to have many values, with different test set for each one, A1, A2, A3, B1, D40, etc. I'll try to edit the question to make it more general

Comment: Give every label an "unidentified" value.  In you example replace A2 with "unidentified".  Simplify your config file by removing the lines that would be the unidentified value.  Every label that passes no tests gets label value unidentified.

Comment: @ravenspoint you can assume that the config was pruned from such lines.  The example that I've added might be more descriptive now. In such a scenario there can be several situations:
1. Item's filename's matched the regex - it's A1
2. Item's filename didn't match the regex but passed test for Property4 of B5 - it's B5
3. Item's filename didn't match the regex but passed other tests - it's A2
4. It either failed or passed all tests - unidentified

Comment: I do not understand your new example, in particular A2.  This has two tests.  Is the value of A set to 2 if BOTH tests pass or if EITHER test passes?

Comment: "In this particular scenario there are only two labels"  ??? In your first example there is only ONE label, A.

Comment: @ravenspoint This table represents tests necessary for item's given properties to pass, so that the item is assigned the label-value pair. Thus we treat the same label with different value as two separate labels

Comment: "we treat the same label with different value as two separate labels"  That makes no sense to me.

Comment: If it makes it easier then you can think of any other letter for the A2. Make it A1, C6, B5. The crux is not in this place anyway

Comment: How many items and how many test do you current have?  Suppose you have 100 tests and 1000 items.  A runtime of 1 hour means that each test is taking you  600 milliseconds.  That is incredibly slow!

Comment: The number of items vary from day to day, it's hard to estimate this number. Right now there's around ~100 labels, with more than 15 properties being checked against a number of tests which is also hard to estimate. The test itself can be more complicated than simply checking a regex, for now we assume that tests implementations have to stay the way they are and are not as bad as it can be. The biggest issue seem to be the fact that right now ALL TESTS from ALL LABELS have to be done to identify the item and we're looking for a way of avoiding that

Comment: Please do a proper timing profile test.  Use a configuration file with a known number of regex tests only and a known number of items.  You have to check how long you need to do each test.  As it is, I suspect you may have a bug in your code that is killing your performance.  Either that or you are using a hopelessly low performance scripting language.

Comment: Well, yeah, the codebase is kept in Python at the moment but the intuition is that it shouldn't be THAT expensive to make it work. Also, staying with "do everything for everything" seems to be irresponsible when we expect both the amount of items to rise as well as new labels with their test sets to be created, that's why I'm looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: Are you aware how slow Python is in this sort of application?  Porting to a compiled language will give you a performance boost of between 50 and 100 times.  This should give you enough time to stay ahead of your increasing size while you seek a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no data structure that will let you skip checking categories, unless you have more information about the category tests than you've mentioned here.

But reading between the lines of your explanation, it sounds like your current problem isn't that you currently have a *bad* data structure, it's that you have *no* data structure.

Parsing text is very expensive, so you'll want to ensure that you parse your config file only once, and put the config in a meaningful object.

What's more, you'll want to ensure that the individual tests don't parse their own definitions for every item. The definition of any given test should be parsed only once, no matter how many items end up getting tested.

For example, you mention that some of the tests use regexes, and you mention in a comment that you're using Python. Parsing a regex is expensive, so Python has some caching logic to retain the parsed [regular expression objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects) of recently-used regexes so that it doesn't have to re-parse them; however, that caching only applies if you have a *small* number of regexes. In your case you can't rely on that. Instead, you should explicitly parse your regexes into regular expression objects (using e.g. `regexObj = re.compile(regexStr)`), and the individual tests should use those objects instead of the original strings (using e.g. `regexObj.match(str)` instead of `re.match(regexStr, str)`).

---

> […] for now we assume that tests implementations have to stay the way they are and are not as bad as it can be.

That's a red flag, and it's worth diving into *why* you're being asked to ignore the majority of possible solutions to the problem you're trying to solve. If there's some sort of organizational dysfunction here, where the test implementations are owned by some other team that doesn't want you touching them, then that's tricky, but the best solution will probably involve diplomacy and tact rather than just accepting this limitation as a hard restriction.

(You should at least consider looking through the test implementations for clear red flags — e.g., anything that involves passing a string into the test and having the test implementation re-parse it for every item — and if you find any, you can at least test what kind of performance improvement you get by fixing them. If you come to your manager saying that you've cut the execution time in half by making some small improvements to test implementations, (s)he's unlikely to tell you that that's too bad and you can't use your improvements.)

---

> The biggest issue seem to be the fact that right now ALL TESTS from ALL LABELS have to be done to identify the item and we're looking for a way of avoiding that

There's no reason to do ALL TESTS from ALL LABELS; you only have to go through labels until you find the first one that matches, and within each label, you only have to go through tests until you find one that doesn't match.

(By the way, you can use some basic Markdown syntax in comments; you probably wanted to use italics, "*all tests* from *all labels*", rather than all-caps? You can use asterisks for that: `*all tests* from *all labels*`.)

---

One additional thing to consider, which might buy you a *bit* of improvement, is multithreading. I'm not terribly familiar with multithreading in Python, but it does exist; see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html. If you run a separate concurrent task for each item, then you'll likely be able to process a large collection of items significantly faster than if you process just one item at a time. (Of course, this depends on how many processor cores you're able to throw at the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a simplified version of your problem in C++.

Here is the input/output for a small test run

```
The configuration ( tests )
A 1: (test) 2: (test2)
B 1: (B)
L3 1: (test)
L4 1: (test)

The items, with label values
Item I1 filename, test
A:0     A:X     B:X     L3:0    L4:0
Item I2 filename, B
A:X     A:X     B:0     L3:X    L4:X
Item I3 filename, test2
A:X     A:1     B:X     L3:X    L4:X
Item I4 filename, X
A:X     A:X     B:X     L3:X    L4:X
```

A profiling test with 1000 items and 50 tests runs in 0.1 secs ( equal to 2 microseconds per test )

The code is here: github.com/JamesBremner/so77827283

Let me know if you would like me to test with some real data.  You will have to provide the test data and answer clearly my questions posted in comments.